# Two players face off, first reaching 4 victories wins the tournament. What's a player's probability to win the tournament?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, bayesian, binomial-distribution

i'm trying to figure out how to solve this.

Here is the problem:

Two players face each other off. At each iteration, a player has a probability $p = 1/3$ to get a victory. There are no draws. The first player to reach 4 victories wins the entire tournament. 
What's the probability that the player wins the tournament?

I am trying to solve this using conditioning.

I define $Xi$ a as a Bernoulli random variable of parameter $p = 1/3$
$$ X = \sum_{i=0}^n X_i$$
and N the number of games in the tournament.

$N$ can be either $4,5,6 or 7$
and $X$ can be either 0,1,2,3(loses the tournament) or 4 (wins the tournament)

I am trying to calculate $P(X=4)$ i.e he wins the tournament

I conditioned $X$ on $N$ so $P(X=4) = P(X=4 | N=4)*P(N=4) + .... + P(X=4 | N=7)*P(N=7)$

I am not sure i calculated $P(N=n)$ and the conditional $X$ probabilities but here is what i tried

$$P(X=4 | N=4) = p^4$$

$$P(X=4 | N=5) = \binom{5}{4}p^4(1-p)$$

$$P(X=4 | N=6) = \binom{6}{4}p^4(1-p)^2$$

$$P(X=4 | N=7) = \binom{7}{4}p^4(1-p)^3$$

and for $P(N=n)$, in order to have n games, either the player won 4 times or lost 4 times for n between 4 and 7

hence

$$P(N=4) = p^4 + (1-p)^4$$

$$P(N=5) = \binom{5}{4}p^4(1-p) + \binom{5}{1}p(1-p)^4$$

$$P(N=6) = \binom{6}{4}p^4(1-p)^2 + \binom{6}{2}p^2(1-p)^4$$

$$P(N=7) = \binom{7}{4}p^4(1-p)^3 + \binom{7}{3}p^3(1-p)^4$$

And then i just use $P(X=4) = P(X=4 | N=4)*P(N=4) + .... + P(X=4 | N=7)*P(N=7)$
and find $P(X=4) = 0.1009$

It doesn't seem right because $P(4\le N\le7)$ isn't equal to 1 and neither is $P(X=4)+P(X\le3)$

I might have calculated my conditional probabilities wrong somewhere over here, please help me out, thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  The desired probability is found by adding the probabilities that the player wins in four games, five games, six games, or seven games.

Comment: As a suggestion, instead of ending the tournament once someone reaches the desired four wins, continue playing exhibition matches until a total of seven games are played.  The winner of the tournament will continue to be the winner regardless of whether we continued with exhibition matches or not, but by continuing with exhibition matches we make our calculations much much easier.  The first player will have won the tournament if he won $4,5,6$ or $7$ of the matches and will have lost the tournament if he won $0,1,2$ or $3$ of the matches.  Now, continue via binomial distribution.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you, i get the desired answer using this approach and it is much simpler!
If one would be interested in the number of games played, how would you approach the problem?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Pardon my lack of formatting skills, i will go through the tutorial and update the post accordingly

Comment: @Roulbacha if you care about splitting it up based on the number of games played, notice that for the first player to win the tournament on the $k$'th game, in the first $k-1$ games there must be exactly $3$ wins for the first player and $k-1-3$ wins for the second player in any order and then the $k$'th game is a win for the first player.  Vice versa if the second player wins the tournament on the $k$'th game.

Comment: @JMoravitz Cheers, seems like proper conditioning. I will try to define my events in that fashion. Thank you for the precious help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the arithmetic,
$$
\sum_{w=4}^7 \left( \frac13 \right)^w \left( \frac23 \right)^{7-w} \binom7w=  \frac{379}{2187} \approx 0.1733
$$